# Ngrok Server failed to allocate tunnel: Invalid authtoken "token"

Tags: linux, token, ngrok

I signed up on ngrok website and tried to set authtoken with the command

```
ngrok -authtoken token 4000
```

and got following error

```
Server failed to allocate tunnel: Invalid authtoken 'token'.
This looks like an ngrok 2.0 authtoken, but you're using ngrok v1.
Download ngrok 2.0 from https://ngrok.com/download
```

Then I downloaded ngrok for linux-32 bit,  as I am using Linux Mint 17.1 32 bit. But still getting the same error. And my ngrok version is 1.6.

Can anybody help with what should be done in order to start ngrok server in this situation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I also face same error ... after edit `~/.ngrok2/ngrok.yml`  it's working.
you just remove that `authtoken` line don't put anything and then save this file and run this command make sure you have in same directory where you install ngrok.

```
$ ./ngrok  http 80
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably created token via `API -> create API key` which is NOT your authtoken. You can find your authtoken in `left menu -> getting started -> your Authtoken`

[image]